# Using clusterize with shield ui grid

Tags: javascript, jquery, datagrid, shieldui, clusterize

Is it possible to use clusterize.js with shieldui grid to enable faster scrolling? I know that virtual scrolling can be enabled, but I need to ensure that there are no blanks when I scroll past a lot of data.
If so, can someone please guide me to a sample implementation?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Shield UI already supports that feature - it is called Virtualization and it can be seen in action [here](http://demos.shieldui.com/web/grid-virtualization/performance-1mil-rows).

Comment: In the million rows example, If you scroll quickly, the grid blanks out. I'm trying to look for ways out there to overcome it, and still achieve comparatively smoother scrolling.